# Variation de la prononciation du o

Tags: phonétique

Est-ce qu'il existe un dialecte du français où l'on prononce le /o/ comme /wo/. Comme exemple:

> Le panneau : /lœpɛ̃wo/

Comment: Ce serait bien de préciser ce qui motive cette question et si "panneau" y est important. Les deux réponses contradictoires montrent que la question peut être interprétée de plusieurs façons.

Comment: En fait, le contexte ou j'ai entendu /panwo/ c'est un client dans un centre d'appel (soutien technique pour les systèmes d'alarmes). Elle dit 'bonjour, j'ai un trouble quelconque sur mon panneau'. J'ai entendu /panwo/ et la prennait pour un Acadienne. Par contre, quand j'ai posé la question à une amie Acadienne, elle disait qu'elle n'a jamais entendu parler de ce phénomène.

Comment: Je plussoie jlliagre. Et ajoute qu'à ma connaissance, aucun dialecte francophone ne prononcerait le mot panneau "panwo". J'y voyais simplement un exemple mal choisi. Mais si effectivement la question a pour source ce que vous pensez avoir entendu panwo, je retire mon intervention sur le créole et miserais plus volontiers sur une mauvaise qualité des communications, ou un francophone non-natif et récent.

Comment: Oui, l'expression *j'ai un trouble quelconque* semble être un anglicisme et irait dans ce sens.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, notamment plusieurs créoles. Ainsi le mot "haute" devient facilement "wot'" ou "wôt'"

[Exemple de source, pour le créole guadeloupéen, page 192](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00169457/document) :

[image]

Comment: Le français parlé aux Antilles réalise les *R* en /w/ et peut aussi faire de même avec les *H* aspirés mais on ne trouve pas d'exemples où un /w/ remplace un /n/ ou est spontanément préfixé à un /o/ comme suggéré dans la question.

Comment: Je ne crois pas avoir lu dans la question de notre ami l'idée que le son devait être "spontanément préfixé" (je vois d'ailleurs mal ce que cet étrange adverbe pourrait vouloir dire, en linguistique : tout a une origine). Il m'est apparu qu'il demandait si des dialectes prononçaient /wo/ ce que le français standard prononcerait /o/. La réponse est oui, entre autres dans des créoles.

La page de la thèse que j'ai postée évoque, très exactement, une "apparition de /w/" devant "/o/", cas distinct de la réalisation du /h/ aspiré en /w/ dont j'ai donné l'exemple avec "haute".

Comment: Quant à savoir si vous jugez cette apparition "spontanée" selon vos critères...

Il m'apparaît néanmoins que cela répondait à la question de l'OP et crois donc utile cet élément de réponse.

Comment: Par spontanément, j'entendais à la fois *naturellement* et *sorti de nulle part*. Trois des quatre /w/ présents dans la thèse citée en exemple semblent avoir comme origine un H graphique, (homard, hausser, haut), muet en France métropolitaine mais réalisé dans les créoles en question, je ne suis pas sûr pour le premier (hauteur?) car les caractères de l'API sont rendus bizarrement dans le pdf. Ils ont aussi la caractéristique d'être des /o/ initiaux alors que la question se réfère à un /o/ intermédiaire.

Comment: Cela dit, ta réponse répond bien à la question quand on l'élargit à tous les /o/ possibles.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne connais pas de variété de français où un /w/ s'insérerait avant ce /o/.

*Le panneau* se prononce généralement **/lə**<sup>1</sup>**.pa.no/**, parfois **/lə.pa.nɔ/**.

D'autre part, je n'ai jamais entendu de nasalisation dans le mot *panneau*. Elle existe peut-être parfois dans le Sud-Ouest, comme avec *année*, mais ça reste à démontrer.

La transcription en API de la question correspond à un hypothétique:

> Leu pain wo

Edit: Dans un contexte où le français acadien est soupçonné, il s'agit peut-être d'un cas de fermeture du /o/ appelé [ouïsme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ou%C3%AFsme):

> /**lə.pa.nʊ**/

Écouter par exemple comment le mot "homard" est prononcé dans [cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWRtnixORXc&t=156s), mais le /w/ qu'on y entend peut-être provient du *H* aspiré, prononcé en acadien..

<sup>1</sup> <sub>L'article ***le*** ne peut se prononcer **/lœ/** que quand on le détache fortement du mot suivant en mettant ainsi l'emphase sur lui: "***LE** panneau*"</sub>